# Paying with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

We have a web-app (react based).

There are two sides to the app.

Can be thought of as an app where companies give tasks to individual talents, approve the payments and at the end of the month, the company gets a single monthly invoice and we take care of paying the talent in their preferred currency/payment method.

Apart from this service we provide these companies a lot of additional features (and hence charge a 3-5% markup on this transaction).

I'd want to discuss what will be the most optimum method since the margin is already really thin for us.

Example: Company has 5 talents and each talent is supposed to get $20 for this month corresponding to the task that they completed

Hence the total bill (invoice) that the company will get from us is $100 + markup fees of let's say 3% = $103

Our commission is $3 and remaining $100 will be split amongst the talents, who will get $20 each.

What we thought of presently is to use Stripe Connect for individual payouts and use the split payment functionality.

But the problem is to receive payments Stripe charges us an additional 2.9% + 30 cents, which will make this thing non-profitable for us.

Hence wanted to get some expertise because there are already softwares that have solved this and I was wondering how ?

Comment: You could write to Stripe Support to have further clarification on their fee model. But AFAIK all payment processors have similar fee structure and it's pretty standard in the industry.

For Stripe you can take a look at their Destination Charge or Separate Charges and Transfers fund flows.

Comment: @orakaro can you please explain more do you mean accepting payments via let's say bank transfers putting money in stripe then paying connected users via stripe connect with 0.25% + 30 cents fee ?

Comment: Stripe Support is a right people to ask that question!